# bfs using queue not working properly

Tags: c, queue, adjacency-matrix, breadth-first-search

I'm implementing **BFS FOR adjacency matrix using queue in C** and here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int G[MAX][MAX],n,visited[MAX];

typedef struct queue{
    int front,rear;
    int data[MAX];
}q;
q p;
void bfs(int);
void insert(q*,int);
int delete(q*);
int empty(q*);
int full(q*);

int main(){
    int i,j,s;
    printf("enter no of vertices\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d",&G[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("enter starting vertex for bfs\n");
    scanf("%d",&s);
    bfs(s);
}

void bfs(int s){
    int i;

    p.front=p.rear=-1;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        visited[i]=0;
    }
    insert(&p,s);

    visited[s]=1;
    while(!empty(&p)){
    s=delete(&p);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(G[s][i]!=0&&visited[i]==0){
                //here it have to store element but it doesn't.
                insert(&p,i);
                visited[i]=1;
                printf("visited %d\n",i);

            }
        }
    }
}
//run to check if queue is full
int full(q *p){
    if(p->rear==MAX-1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
//run to check if queue is empty
int empty(q *p){
    if(p->rear==-1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
//run to insert element to rear where front<=rear
void insert(q *p,int x){
    if(full(p)){
        printf("full\n");
    }
    if(empty(p)){
        p->front=p->rear=0;
        p->data[p->rear]=x;
    }
    else{
        p->rear=p->rear+1;
        p->data[p->rear]=x;
    }
}
 //run to delete element from front
int delete(q *p){
    int x;
    if(empty(p)){
        printf("empty\n");
    }
    else if(p->front==p->rear==0){
        x=p->data[p->front];
        p->front=p->rear=-1;
    }
    else{
        x=p->data[p->front];
        p->front=p->front+1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

what is wrong with this code? It gives wrong answer.The queue is not storing
all elements. In this example where input is

> enter no of vertices 8
>
> 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
>
> 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
>
> 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
>
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
>
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
>
> 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
>
> 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
>
> 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
>
> enter starting vertex 0

**estimated output:-**

> visited 0
>
> visited 1
>
> visited 2
>
> visited 3
>
> visited 4
>
> visited 5
>
> visited 6
>
> visited 7

**But the result is**

> visited 0
>
> visited 1
>
> visited 2
>
> visited 3
>
> visited 4
>
> visited 5
>
> visited 7
>
> visited 6

Comment: please post the code here

Comment: While `a = b = 0` assigns a value of 0 to both `a` and `b`, the expression `a == b == 0` does not check whether both variables are zero; you should use an expression like `a == 0 && b == 0` in `delete`.

Comment: Also, please post your code here and be more specific than "it gives wrong answer". Which answer does it give for which input and what did you expect?

Comment: The error is with your queue implementation, which doesn't detect when the queue is empty correctly. Fix that first.

Comment: I fixed it . Now it gives segmentation fault.